# Switch from header to cpp-File in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, header-files, netbeans-8

Is there a fast way or short-cut to switch from the header-file to the cpp-files in Netbeans?

And vice versa?

Comment: A quick google search reveals [this plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3359/c-c-switch-source-header) and [this tutorial](https://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/switch-h-cpp/switch-h-cpp-plugin.html). The same tutorial has methods to improve the usability of the plugin by adding keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah - that's what i was looking for. Thank you. What did you actually search? My Search-Query was misunderstood.

Comment: @Qohelet did you install any plugin to achieve that??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ - there's over your editor a small icon "c/h" on the very right. No plugin required as I remember

Answer (score 3):

For me:

**Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609270201)**

just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shif</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will do the trick...